# FIAT 500 sunroof will not close

Tags: fiat, sunroof

The sliding glass sunroof on my 2014 Abarth 595 (FIAT 500) will not close from the tilted position, it will close but just immediately re-opens to the tilted position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the sunroof calibration fixed this issue, the full procedure is:

- Begin with the the sunroof fully closed, it can be closed with a hex key if this is completely impossible with the switches (see owners manual).
- Turn the ignition key to MAR (first position).
- Hold the close button for approximately 10 seconds until the sunroof motor makes an audible click.
- Within 5 seconds, release the close button then press and hold it again.
- Continue to hold the close button while the sunroof goes through a full open and close movement.
- Once the roof is closed again, release the close button and turn the ignition off and on again.

After this the sunroof should function properly.